# Proof doubt about the "coefficients formulas" for $a_{k},b_{k}$ of a "real trigonometric polynomial"

Tags: calculus

I'm studying the following theorem: "Let $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real trigonometric polynomial of order $\le n$, that is: $p(t)=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{k}cos(kt)+b_{k}sin(kt))$. Then we can write: $a_{k}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}p(t)cos(kt)dt\;\forall k\ge 0;b_{k}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}p(t)sin(kt)dt\;\forall k \ge 1$. I omit $b_{k}$ as is similar to $a_{k}$ except we multiply by $sin(ht)$ instead of $cos(ht)$. I understood that the main idea is to know "Werner's formulas" to evaluate $cos(ht)cos(kt);sin(ht)cos(kt);sin(ht)sin(kt)$ but my problem is with the sigma notation, basically. In fact: $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}p(t)cos(ht)dt=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_{k}cos(kt)+b_{k}sin(kt))]cos(ht)dt=\frac{a_{0}}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(ht)dt+\sum_{k=1}^{n}[a_{k}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(kt)cos(ht)dt+b_{k}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}sin(kt)cos(ht)dt]=0+\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\frac{a_{k}}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos((h-k)t)dt+\frac{a_{k}}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos((h+k)t)dt]=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\frac{a_{k}}{2}[\frac{sin((h-k)t)}{(h-k)}]_{-\pi}^{\pi}+\frac{a_{k}}{2}[\frac{sin((h+k)t)}{(h+k)}]_{-\pi}^{\pi}]$. Here I can't see how to proceed, and the sigma notation I think is a problem to get the final result.

Comment: Hint: what's the value of $\displaystyle{\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos (nt) \;\mathrm dt}$ for integer $n$, when $n=0$ and when $n\ne0$?

Comment: I think we can say $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(nt)dt=\begin{cases} 0\;n\ne 0\\ 2\pi\;n=0 \end{cases}$.

Comment: Fine. Now can you simplify your integrals?